# Mesh deforms when parenting to the armature

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, parent

I was trying to make a character rig , I have done all the steps necessary except one , when I parented the armature to the mesh , the mesh went haywire.

This is an image before parenting :-

[image]

And this is an image after parenting:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: it might be because of the IK pole angle? Maybe share your file?

Comment: Avoid using any ngones. try usingonly quads or tris.

Comment: i have added the file

Comment: It seems that the file you uploaded is corrupted. 13.5 KB, missing data blocks. Please try again with a verified file, thanks.

Comment: I want to answer but file is missing!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9 out of 10 times, rigging problems are caused by problems in scaling.
make sure that figure feet are at world center and the armature fits in it.
Before you autorig, apply scale(and other transforms) to the mesh and
apply scale (and transforms) to the bone system