# Mesh is deforming in Pose mode without moving the bones

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, rigify, pose-mode

For some reason when I switch from Rest Mode to Pose Mose the mesh of the head "squishes" without the bones moving.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? I've tried ALT+R,S,G and Clear All Transforms and got no change.

The file can be located here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o12SfNnrZHMg9C7y0xWyL0AtiMrA0x1C/view?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: visit - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190495/mesh-deforms-when-parenting-to-the-armature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bone called *DEF-spine.003* is supposed to stretch towards the bone called *tweak_spine.004*, but as you can see it doesn't completely:

[image]

It's because the *Stretch Original Length* value has been changed... To come back to the default one, click on the X button:

[image]